# wordpress website refreshes in IE

Tags: jquery, wordpress, refresh

I have went threw and changed everything and took out javascript and css and nothing. I am at a loss at why this wordpress theme reloads. Anyone see anything like this before. i have taken out a lot of jquery but have put it back to normal so other people can see it.

http://www.wpcreations.net/wptest/

Comment: **Visit my site and tell me what is wrong is NOT a good question!**

Comment: ONly happen in IE. I am using IE 8 . I have looked everywhere. Can CSS reload a page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your Internet Explorer caching the website and not reloading the changes.

Check this out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263070

You'll want the top setting, "on every visit".

Comment: well i changed font settings as it was pulling google fonts and causing a refresh. I think IE was pulling down some fonts to use and then refresh getting google fonts.